# Interchanging Positions of Limit and Integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

> Find $ \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} q(x) \frac{\exp \big(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\big)}{\sigma} dx $, where $ q(x) $ is "erf(x).

I need to compute the expression shown above. I believed the dominated convergence theorem could be used to solve this. But based on the provided answer, it does not seem possible. I would appreciate that would help me in sketching the general steps I need to follow. Or is there a simpler way to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can calculate the limes explicitly as follows. First, recall that the error function is given by
$$q(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_x^\infty \exp(-x^2) \, \mathrm{d} x$$
and therefore $q(x) \le 2$ because of 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-y^2) \, dy = \sqrt{\pi}.$$
We start with the change of variables $ y= (x-\mu)/\sqrt{2 \sigma^2}$ to get
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty q(x) \frac{\exp \Big( - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \Big)}{\sigma} \, dx = \sqrt{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty q(\sqrt{2} \sigma y  + \mu) \exp(-y^2) \, dy.$$
If $y >0$, then $q(\sqrt{2} \sigma y  + \mu) \rightarrow 0$ for $\sigma \rightarrow \infty$ and if $y <0$, then $q(\sqrt{2} \sigma y  + \mu) \rightarrow 2$ for $\sigma \rightarrow \infty$. Thus, since the integrand is bounded by $2 \exp(-y^2)$, we get after an application of Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem that
$$\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty q(x) \frac{\exp \Big( - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \Big)}{\sigma} \, dx = 2 \sqrt{2} \int_{-\infty}^0 \exp(-y^2) \, dy = \sqrt{2\pi},$$
where we used the Gaussian integral formula again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited the question. The original problem is shown above. I believed I could interchange the positions but I was wrong

Comment: I have edited my answer, too, giving an explicit formula for the limes.

Comment: thank you. You have found an upper bound $ 2\exp(-y^2 ) $ for the integrand. If I understand correctly, you have evaluated the extreme cases. But how can I verify that the bound also holds pointwise? Also, what happens when $ y = 0 $??

Comment: First: $y=0$ is a Lebesgue null set and therefore can be neglected. Second: One has the bound $0 \le q(\sqrt{2}\sigma y+\mu) \exp(-y^2) \le 2 \exp(-y^2)$ and this is a pointwise statement. So, I don't really unterstand your question.

Comment: Now I understand better the first point. Would you please elaborate a bit on the Lebesgue null set? Because for this case we would have $ \sigma y $, where $ \sigma $ tends to $ \infty$ whereas $ y = 0 $. Is this product zero?

Comment: We integrate and here the integration over one single point, that is $\{0\}$, have no contribution. In other words, we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f dx = \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}} f dx$ for any $L^1$ integrable function $f$ with the respect of the Lebesgue-measure. (The same holds for any measurable null set.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply again. Yes, it is clear for me that leaving out one infinitesimal point is not going to affect the integral. But my point is that $ \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow \infty} \sigma y $ when $y=0$ is undetermined, right? How can I state that this non-evaluated value is nkt going to have any influence in the final result. Let's say, can we find a bound and prove that it will not be $\infty$

Comment: As I already said, you don't have to consider the case $y=0$. (You can just restrict the integration to the region $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. That is a standard argument in measure theory.) By the way: If $y=0$, then the value is always $q(\mu)$.